# Does Evasion work against Elemental Adept'ed spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, class-feature, ranger

I really think its a silly question, but does evasion from a ranger reduce damage from a spell (Dex save), cast from a caster with Elemental adept?

Answer (score 26):

### Yes, Evasion still applies to spells cast by an Elemental Adept

[Elemental Adept](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/customization-options#ElementalAdept) states that:

> Spells you cast ignore resistance to damage of the chosen type.

And the [ranger's Evasion feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#SuperiorHunter%E2%80%99sDefense-341) states that:

> When you are subjected to an effect, such as a red dragon’s fiery breath or a lightning bolt spell, that allows you to make a Dexterity saving throw to take only half damage, you instead take no damage if you succeed on the saving throw, and only half damage if you fail.

Evasion doesn't grant you resistance or immunity to the damage, it simply halves or zeroes the damage you take - which has the same numerical effect as resistance or immunity, but is not actually resistance or immunity. Since Evasion doesn't grant resistance, it's not overcome by Elemental Adept - the two features don't have any interaction with each other.

Aside, this also means that, while multiple sources of resistance to the same damage do not stack together, Evasion and resistance can both apply to incoming damage, so a ranger with a relevant resistance might halve and halve again damage from a hostile effect, reducing it to only a quarter (or most likely a little less, due to rounding down twice).

Answer (score 20):

## Evasion is not resistance

While both would halve the damage taken, they are not the same. Elemental Adept would let the spell's damage ignore resistance, but it does not do the same to other sources of damage halving.